# Why I got an error type assertion on object literals is forbidden, use a type annotation instead.tslint(no-object-literal-type-assertion)?

Tags: typescript

I have code in TS

```
interface Context {
    out: vscode.OutputChannel,
    myPorts: number[]
}

const outputChannel = vscode.window.createOutputChannel('my-run');

    const ctx = {
        out: OutputChannel,
        myPorts: []
    } as Context;
```

I got error Type assertion on object literals is forbidden, use a type annotation instead.tslint(no-object-literal-type-assertion

Comment: I recommend checking the article to understand the motivation to have that rule https://medium.com/@kreznykov/there-is-no-point-to-use-typescript-in-your-project-if-you-dont-care-about-types-68131deeb43a

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-object-literal-type-assertion.md) forbids the use of `as` to annotate types. Instead, you should use the type annotation `var: type` syntax, as in:

```
    const ctx: Context = {
        out: OutputChannel,
        myPorts: []
    };
```

That syntax may throw some errors in some cases and then you may need to cast the object literal to `any` with `as any` (which is actually allowed by the rule):

```
    const ctx: Context = {
        out: OutputChannel,
        myPorts: []
    } as any;
```

Now, I'm not sure if your asking about how to get your code to comply with the rule  (I already answered that), or **why the warning appears in the first place**. If so, this depends on your tslint configuration, and you may need to provide some extra info if your configuration is not standard. If it is, you must go to the `tslint.json` file an add:

`no-object-literal-type-assertion: false`

to the `rules` field of the json.

Answer (score 6):

You can bypass the [no-object-literal-type-assertion](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-object-literal-type-assertion/) rule by casting your object to `unknown` before assigning it to another type.

**Example:**

```
const ctx = {
  out: OutputChannel,
  myPorts: []
} as unknown as Context;
```